# How can I retrieve the event Id from single instance of recurring series using Advanced Calendar Service and Calendar API?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

When I use the Spreadsheet App service .getId() on a single instance of a recurring event, it returns the IcalUID for the recurring series, and not the individual event Id. This is a problem because I am trying to log individual instances to a spreadsheet and I want to find the unique identifier of the instance to reference the event and copy the details to the corresponding row, but I am only getting details from the first instance of the series.

I looked through the documentation on Advanced Calendar Service and it appears that I will need to use the Calendar API to achieve this. I have enabled the Calendar API and created an API key. How can I modify my previous script to return the event Id from a single instance in a recurring series using the Calendar API?

```
function updateEventsGeneric() {
 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("EventsRange");
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id_cal);

  var date = new Date();

    let day = date.getDate() ;
    let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let year_short = year.toString().slice(-2)
    
  var currentDate = `${month}-${day}-${year}`;

  var events = cal.getEventsForDay(new Date(currentDate));
  var row = sheet.getLastRow()+1
  var values = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var title = events[i].getTitle();
    var clientName = '';
    var event_date = new Date(events[i].getStartTime().toDateString());
    var employEmail = [];
    var clientEmail = [];
    var start_time = events[i].getStartTime();
    var end_time = events[i].getEndTime();
    var loc = events[i].getLocation();
    var event_id = events[i].getId();

    for (var j = 0; j < guestList.length; j++) {
      var email = guestList[j].getEmail();
      
      employees.some(({emailad}) => emailad === email) ? employEmail.push(email): clientEmail.push(email)
     
    };

  values.push([title, formulaString, event_date, employEmail, clientEmail, start_time, end_time, `=G${i + row}-F${i + row}`, loc, event_id]);
  }

  
  sheet.getRange(row , 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  var cellValue = sheet.getRange(row, 2, values.length, 1).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(row, 2, values.length, 1).setValues(cellValue);
  sheet.getRange(row, 6, values.length,2).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm");
  sheet.getRange(row, 8, values.length,1).setNumberFormat("[hh]:mm:ss");

  
}

function listEventsFromOneCalendar() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
        .getSheetByName("ExistingEvents");

  var source = "testemail@group.calendar.google.com";
  var srcCalId = Calendar.Calendars.get(source).id;

  var syncdays = 30;
  var now = new Date();
  var min = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
  var max = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate() + syncdays);

  var srcEvents = Calendar.Events.list(srcCalId, {
    timeMin: min.toISOString(),
    timeMax: max.toISOString(),
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
  }).items;

  /*
   * To store events data in a spreadsheet we need
   * to construct a 2-dim array
   *
   */
  var output = [];

  /*
   * 'srcEvents' is an array of event objects.
   *
   * Every event object is passed as 'e' to the anonymous
   * function.
   *
   */
  srcEvents.forEach(function(e){
    // Construct an event array (1-dim)
    var event = [];

    /*
     * Returns "" if object value is 'null' or 'undefined'
     *   otherwise returns the object value.
     *
     */
    event.push(e.summary || "");
    event.push(e.start.dateTime || "");
    event.push(e.end.dateTime || "");
    event.push(e.id || "");
    event.push(e.location || "");

    // Push each event array to output (2-dim array).
    output.push(event);
  });

  var header = [
                 "Title/Subject",
                 "Start Time",
                 "End Time",
                 "Description",
                 "Location"
               ];

  // Insert header at the top of the output.
  output.unshift(header);

  sheet.clearContents();

  sheet.getRange(1, 1, output.length, header.length)
  .setValues(output);
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `When I use the Spreadsheet App service .getId() on a single instance of a recurring event, it returns the IcalUID for the recurring series, not the individual event Id.`. And, in your script, there are undeclared variables and unused variables. And, from `var events = cal.getEventsForDay(new Date(currentDate));`, do you want to retrieve the events of the specific day? So, I cannot understand your expected values. Can I ask you the detail of your question?

Comment: I am trying to get the event Id from a single instance to add to the spreadsheet, but I only get the ICalUID for the full recurring series. So if I created the series in January, but I select an event from this week and use .getId(), I will get the Id from the first appt in January instead of the one from this week. I am looking to get the unique identifier for the single event instance so that I can reference that event and get details in another script, by using the saved Id in this one.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question and your expected values. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your expected values. I apologize for this. For example, in order to correctly understand your expected situation, can you provide the sample output values you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: Hi Tainake, thank you! I added another script that outputs the value that I need below the first - the desired output is a string that looks like 't30op3ge0ente4jol74gi145vs_20221217T180000Z' rather than '0hjb01nlp6e88tsfn8kualo6j4@google.com'. The id ending in @google.com references the first instance of the recurring series, rather than the specific instance of the event I am trying to save. If I use something like CalendarApp.getEvents().getId(), I get the ICalUID. When I use the second script, I get the unique ID for the event.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your expected values. I apologize for this. In your added script, isn't `e.id` your expected value? Because I thought that in your script, `e.id` includes each event ID of the recurring series. If I misunderstood your expected value, I apologize.